# Sum based on a value in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to sum column "Runs" when MatchN is x, B is between i and j.

```
MatchN  I   B   Runs
1000887 1   0.1 1
1000887 1   0.2 3
1000887 1   0.3 0
1000887 1   0.4 2
1000887 1   0.5 1
```

I tried using for loop but not able to crack it so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please make sure you include (at least some of) your code and your results to make it easier for users to assist.

Comment: Sure. Will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can first use a filter, and then sum op the `B` column, like:

```
df[(df['MatchN'] == x) & (i <= df['B']) & (df['B'] <= j)]['Runs'].sum()
#  \_________________________ _________________________/ \___ __/\_ __/
#                            v                               v     v
#                        filter part                     column sum part
```

So the filter part, is the logical and of three conditions:

1. `df['MatchN'] == x`;
2. `i <= df['B']`; and
3. `df['B'] <= j`.

We use the `&` operator to combine the three filters. Next we select these rows with `df[<filter-condition>]` (with `<filter-condition>` our previously discussed filter).

Next we select the `Runs` column of the filtered rows, and then finally we calculate the `.sum()` of that column.

Comment: Thanks Willem. I used the filtering technique and it worked. I am not trying to use a for loop to run this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `query`:

```
x = '1000887'
i = 0.2
j = 0.4
df.query('MatchN == @x and @i <= B <= @j')['Runs'].sum()
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. will try this too and report back.